# Angular Web components -> *ngIf directive Error

Tags: angular, web-component

I am new to webComponents. I am facing an issue, please would you help me?

Let me tell you what i have done till now :
I created an Angular shell like project with command -

```
ng new MyAngularAppHolder --create-application=true
```

then i created an app within that called as shared-

```
ng generate application shared --routing=false --style=less --skip-install=true
```

next i created a module within it called shared and added a navigationBar Component-

```
ng g m shared
ng g c shared/navBar
```

then i added some html within  my component  like so-

```
<button (click)="hello()" >hi</button>
<div *ngIf="isBool" >hi</div>
```

with its ts having code -

```
isBool = true
  hello(){
    alert('hello')
    this.isBool = !this.isBool;
  }
```

then i put the component in App.component.html
next i tried running my project till now-

```
ng s shared
```

i got the button and when i clicked on it, the div did show up. so until here it worked fine.
then i wanted to make this as a web component so, i created a new project -

```
ng generate application my-app-1 --routing=true --style=less --skip-install=true
```

then i installed angular elements

```
ng add @angular/elements
```

so in the my-app-1 application's app.module.ts,
i imported that NavBar Component, Injector, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
then i declared CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in schema,
next in constructor i added the parameter for injector of type Injector which would be then the config for createCustomElements
so then i created custom element by createCustomElement giving the tag name and the createCustomElement element declaration

```
import { Injector, NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements'
import { NavBarComponent } from 'projects/shared/src/app/shared/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas : [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector : Injector){
    customElements.define('my-app-nav-bar', createCustomElement(NavBarComponent, {injector}))
  }
 }
```

so after doing this i put the tag in html

```
<my-app-nav-bar></my-app-nav-bar>
```

i run the project

```
ng s my-app-1 --port 4300
```

so in the UI i can now see the button that i wrote in the shared application.

The issue Iam facing :
so that *ngIf directive that i wrote is not being affected and throws me an error,

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

I tried various solutions -
from restarting the server
to explictly extending CommonModule on NavBarComponent.

and i also checked-
angular documents on this and i gained nothing related to this issue

yet the problem still persists, can anyone please help me on how to solve the weird problem?

any help would be very appreciated, Thanks in advance

Update: I have tried adding strategyFactory for the config and that doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

Please make sur to import `CommonModule` like this in your `SharedModule`:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  

@NgModule({
 imports: [CommonModule],
})

...

class SharedModule{}
```

Then in your `AppModule` you should have somethin like this :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   NavBarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
  ]
})
export class VlansModule { }
```

Comment: if you meant to import in AppModule of my project where i imported, i did that and it did not work and if you meant in the shared, it didnt work wither and didnt work when i imported in both at the same time either

Comment: I updated my response by using your shared module where you will declare all your shared modules & components, then use it in your AppModule and also declare NavBarComponent

Comment: Thank You it is now working although now i see there is no point in creating a custom element